# Changing several elements in a list using list comprehension

Tags: python, type-conversion, list-comprehension

An example:

```
example = [None, b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'1', None, None, b'8', b'56', b'66', b'77', b'1', None]
```

I need to change values in this list in the following way: `bytes` should be converted to `int`, `None` to `0` and every 6th and 7th element to a `bool`. The expected output:

```
expected_output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, True, False, 0, 8, 56, 66, 77, True, False]
```

My attempt:

```
[int(value) if value else bool(value) if index in (5,6) else 0 for index, value in enumerate(example)]
```

The result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, True, False, 0, 8, 56, 66, 77, 0, 0]
```

I know there is a problem in this part of my code:

```
[int(value) if value else bool(value) if index in (5,6) else 0 for index, value in enumerate(example)]
                                       ^
                                       |
                                       |
```

How can I change every 6th and 7th element to a `bool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether the index modulo 7 (the number of elements in each group) is 5 or 6. But you also need to do that first since `b'1'` also passes the `if value` test:

```
[bool(value) if index % 7 in (5,6) else int(value) if value else 0 for index, value in enumerate(example)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, True, False, 0, 8, 56, 66, 77, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was help me.

Comment: @MrOldSir no worries - I'm glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

The more logic you add to this list comprehension the more unreadable it will become. I'd suggest you to go with a normal `if`/`elif` statement here:

```
for ix, i in enumerate(example):
    if ix % 7 in (5,6):
        example[ix] = bool(i)
    elif not i:
        example[ix] = 0
    elif isinstance(i, bytes):
        example[ix] = int(i)
```

---

```
print(example)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, True, False, 0, 8, 56, 66, 77, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic

You can implement *rotation* with `%`(modulo) operator.

```py
example = [
    None, b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'1', None,
    None, b'8', b'56', b'66', b'77', b'1', None,
]

results = [
    bool(value) if index % 7 in {5, 6} else
    int(value) if value else 0
    for index, value in enumerate(example)
]
print(results)
```

output:

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, True, False, 0, 8, 56, 66, 77, True, False]
```

#### Pythonic

But, there is some more pythonic way:

```py
import itertools

example = [
    None, b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'1', None,
    None, b'8', b'56', b'66', b'77', b'1', None,
]
converters = itertools.cycle(itertools.chain(
    itertools.repeat(lambda x: int(x) if x else 0, 5),
    itertools.repeat(bool, 2),
))

results = [
    converter(value) for converter, value in zip(converters, example)
]
print(results)
```

output: same with above.

#### Explanation

- [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle): Make a cyclic iterator.
- [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain): Concatenate iterables.
- [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat): Make iterator with repeating by specified number.
- So `converters = ...` part means: `lambda x: int(x) if x else 0` fucntion with five times, `bool` with two times, and repeat this cycle!
- You can add multiple rules for each position without complicated `if`-`else`.